# How to get request header value from http request in spring mvc using custom annotaion?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

How to get request header value from http request in spring mvc based on custom annotation condition on Field level Element type without using any handlerMapping object?

Comment: post code as example to clarify  your scenario

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you're asking, Spring MVC already offers an annotation to map request headers, see the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestheader)

```
@RequestMapping("/displayHeaderInfo.do")
public void displayHeaderInfo(@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding") String encoding,
        @RequestHeader("Keep-Alive") long keepAlive) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: As per my understanding, the need here is to create an annotation like `@Encoding`. Rather than writing `@RequestHeader("Accept-Encoding")` we can directly mention `@Encoding`. This could be especially helpful if we are healing with some custom header. Maybe the custom header needs some decoding or other type of processing.